# Extrair vetores de um vetor de conjunto de nomes de vetores e juntar num único vetor

Tags: array, r

Tenho um vetor que contém que contém nomes de outros vetores. Por exemplo:

```
teste
[1] "vetor_arte"   "vetor_rio"    "vetor_parque"

vetor_arte
[1]  1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41

vetor_rio
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

vetor_parque
[1]  5 15 17 27
```

Quero um vetor geral:

```
vetor_geral
[1] 1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41 6  7  8  9 10 5 15 17 27
```

De forma manual eu consigo, porém quero fazer de forma dinâmica pois o meu vetor inicial as vezes irá conter nomes de 3, 4, 2, 5 vetores. Não é um vetor fixo.

Estou com dificuldades de desenvolver essa lógica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro vou criar os dados a serem utilizados neste problema:

```
teste <- c("vetor_arte", "vetor_rio", "vetor_parque")

vetor_arte <- c(1,  3,  4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 29, 30, 41)
vetor_rio <- c(6,  7,  8,  9, 10)
vetor_parque <- c(5, 15, 17, 27)
```

A função `ls` lista os objetos na memória do `R`. Aqui vou pedir para ela listar todos os objetos que tenham `vetor` em seu some:

```
ls(pattern="vetor")
[1] "vetor_arte"   "vetor_parque" "vetor_rio"
```

A seguir, combino este resultado com a função `lapply`, de modo a criar uma lista com os três vetores desejados. Perceba que perdi a informação sobre o nome dos vetores, mas isso não é importante neste caso.

```
lista <- lapply(ls(pattern="vetor"), get)
lista
[[1]]
[1]  1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41

[[2]]
[1]  5 15 17 27

[[3]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Por fim, crio o objeto `vetor_geral` ao desfazer a lista criada no passo anterior:

```
vetor_geral <- unlist(lista)
vetor_geral
[1]  1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41  5 15 17 27  6  7  8  9 10
```

A desvantagem deste método é colocar os vetores em ordem alfabética. Caso a ordem `vetor_arte`, `vetor_rio` e `vetor_parque` seja importante, minha solução não funciona a contento.

Answer (score 4):

O que quer pode ser feito com uma única instrução R base.
A função pricipal a ser usada é `mget`. Depois é só transformar em vetor (`unlist`) sem nomes (`unname`).

```
vetor_geral <- unname(unlist(mget(teste)))
vetor_geral
# [1]  1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41  6  7  8  9 10  5 15 17 27
```

**Dados.**

```
teste <- scan(what = character(), text = '
"vetor_arte"   "vetor_rio"    "vetor_parque"')

vetor_arte <- scan(text = '
1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41')

vetor_rio <- scan(text = '
6  7  8  9 10')

vetor_parque <- scan(text = '
5 15 17 27')
```